# Adding IPC support to existing Python applications

Tags: python, ipc, cpython

I'm starting with Python, I'm trying to understand how Cpython works with both the usual "Python console" from the OS shell and the Python APIs provided by some applications, now I need some kind of solution that can provide a callback mechanism and a communication channel with other processes/applications .

I was wondering if there is an easy way for this, for example modifying 2-3 key values before compiling Cpython or the modules for my Python APIs, after all this kind of features are pretty common as a requirement for modern applications.

So, any hidden IPC related feature for Cpython ?

Thanks.

Comment: What you are asking here? Your question makes very little sense. Can you instead try to describe your bigger problem and we can  provide answer how to do it with Python. Please edit the question and tell more background and why you are doing what you think you are doing.

Comment: @MikkoOhtamaa some methos/API is used, I get notified. A simple callback mechanism.

Comment: So you want to get notification when some of internal Python methods are called? Why?

Comment: @MikkoOhtamaa yes, the idea is to keep track of any call, as an extra feature I would also like to access data structures provided and builded inside a given Python console.

Comment: There are tools called profiles which probably will solve your problem for you. However you still don't tell why you want to give track of calls.

Comment: @MikkoOhtamaa probably I'm not explaining my self clearly here, I want to provide this as a feature, I'm not interested in debugging or profiling anything, I would like to take an application with Python APIs like Blender or just another one, tweak what I need to tweak, and then provide a new feature to alert whenever a method is used. My question is more about how to modify a Python API set to provide callbacks and IPC than learn how to do this on my machine only.

Comment: Ok, thanks! This gives the clue what you are doing :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to explicitly map functions and objects to remote API, there is no automatic way to turn all code remote-aware (though some code can be turned remote aware as is). However, due to nature of Python dynamicity, creating automatic "mappers" is not very difficult.

There are some common remote procedure call (RPC) and interprocess event notification protocols Python supports out of the box, or very easily with additional packages

- zerorpc https://github.com/dotcloud/zerorpc-python (from examples, looks like least integration efffort)
- XML-RPC http://docs.python.org/2/library/xmlrpclib.html
- ProtoRPC (by Google) https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/protorpc/overview
- DBUS (Linux) http://dbus.freedesktop.org/doc/dbus-python/doc/tutorial.html

Comment: Thanks, this is my first dive into the IPC world, I hope that this will be easy and effective

Comment: the automatic way to run a callback whenever any function is called is [`sys.settrace()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.settrace). Though it probably shouldn't be used in the OPs case.